# how to make join after where condition with peewee

Tags: python, mysql, join, peewee

Is that possible making join after where condition like that

```
query = (AppCompany
            .select(AppCompany,User)
            .join(User)
            .where(AppCompany.status_id==request.args.status_id)
        )

if request.args.industry:
    query = query.switch(AppCompany).join(AppCompanyToIndustry)
    query = query.where(AppCompanyToIndustry.industry_id==request.args.industry)
```

I tired but it throwed this error : **"ValueError: A join condition must be specified."**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide a join condition

```
query = query.switch(AppCompany)
             .join(AppCompanyToIndustry)
             .where(AppCompanyID == AppCompanyToIndustryID)
```

Here you should replace `AppCompanyID` and `AppCompanyToIndustryID` with proper column

Comment: Thanks. Peewee already support joining after where condition. It throwed error because of my code's bugs. I fixed and workted correctly.